# Dynamically Creating a Radio Button name in Angular 8(Typescript, HTML, SCSS)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, scss-lint

I am having some challenges creating a radio button name Dynamically. How can I Dynamically generate a radio button name. Here is my html code

```html
<table>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" #radio [id]="inputId" name="radio" />
        <label [for]="inputId">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        </label>
    </td>
    <br />
    <br />
</table>
```

I am also passing a string to the Radio Buttton Component like this

```html
<radio-button>
    <b>Radio Button 1</b>
</radio-button>
<radio-button>
    <b>Radio Button 2</b>
</radio-button>
<radio-button>
    <b>Radio Button 3</b>
</radio-button>
<radio-button>
    <b>Radio Button 4</b>
</radio-button>
```

My `name` attribute is hard-coded to the component like `name="radio"`. I want to generate a dynamically assigned names for the radio button

Comment: `ng-content` projects content. Are you passing a string into the component `<example-component>Radio Button Label</example-component>`

Comment: Hi, I am passing a string to the Radio Buttton Component like

``` html
<radio-button>
        <b>
          Radio Button 1
        </b>
      <radio-button>
      <radio-button>
        <b>
          Radio Button 2
        </b>
      <radio-button>
      <radio-button>
        <b>
          Radio Button 3
        </b>
      <radio-button>
      <radio-button>
        <b>
          Radio Button 4
        </b>
      <radio-button>
```

Comment: As of right now, your code works [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cy1ptb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Hi, what happens is that my name attribute is hard-coded  name="radio". I want a generic name( dynamically assigned names) for the radio button

Comment: You could bind it to a local variable `[name]="localVariable"`

Comment: I am a bit new to this. 
You mentioned binding to a local variable [name]="localVariable"  and what will the "local Variable" contain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208464/discussion-between-dane-brouwer-and-doctore).

Answer (score 1):

You can try a for loop inside your html and put radio button code inside that and have your radio button tag something like below:

```
<input type="radio" name="rbtn[{{i}}]" [attr.name]="i" [value]="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you pass separate name to each radio button then you will be able to select multiple radio options. If you pass same name to multiple radio buttons then you will be able to select only one radio button.

**How to Pass Dynamic Name?**

If `<radio-button>` is a separate component. then you can pass the name as an attribute to the component like this.

```
<radio-button name="radio-1"></radio-button>
```

then in your `radio-button` component you can accept the coming attribute with `@Input` decorator.

```
@Input name: string;
```

Now you can pass this variable to your component html.

```
<input type="radio" #radio [id]="inputId" [name]="name" />
```

If you want to pass the variable to the attribute then you need to use `[]` for one way binding.

See an example here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-radio-name